# strip_tags with json data went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, strip-tags

When I strip html tags with strip_tags in rails of the json data,it returns the wrong data:

```
the original data is: "<p><em><span style=\"font-size: 96px; \">test</span></em></p>"
data.to_json is: "\"<p><em><span style=\\\"font-size: 96px; \\\">\\u9ed1\\u4f53\\u5b57\\u54e6</span></em></p>\""
the stripped data that after strip_tags is: "\""
```

Who can tell me the reason or other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order to :

```
strip_tags(data).to_json
```

You will get "test" as expected.

The reason is being html-scanner (used by strip_tags) strips the encoded "test" value.

Comment: oh,sorry,I can't.I want to get the json data of a model set,and I don't want use strip_tags with the model one by one and with each attribute of the model on by one.